# In Facebook with C# /me/accounts with manage_pages permission does not show any pages

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, model-view-controller, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am trying to fetch pages data in Facebook using c# MVC. Even though I give manage_pages permission (Scope) it does not show any pages when I run my code. Here is where pagelist is showing 0

```
string Accounts = "/me/accounts";
JSONObject pageData = api.Get(Accounts);
var data = pageData.Dictionary["data"];
List<JSONObject> pageList = data.Array.ToList<JSONObject>();
ViewBag.pageList = pageList;
```

Below is the Code that I tried

```
public ActionResult returnfromfb()
    {
        string app_id = "AppID";
        string app_secret = "AppSecret";
        string scope = "manage_pages,publish_stream,status_update,user_about_me,user_hometown,user_location,email,offline_access";

        string code = Request.QueryString["code"];
        if (code == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect(string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}",
                app_id, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, scope));

        }

        string AccessToken = "";
        try
        {
            if (code != null)
            {
                string str = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}&code={3}&client_secret={4}",
                app_id, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, scope, Request["code"].ToString(), app_secret);

                HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(str);
                req.Method = "POST";
                req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                byte[] Param = Request.BinaryRead(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentLength);
                string strRequest = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Param);

                req.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;

                StreamWriter streamOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
                streamOut.Write(strRequest);
                streamOut.Close();
                StreamReader streamIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
                string strResponse = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
                if (strResponse.Contains("&expires"))
                    strResponse = strResponse.Substring(0, strResponse.IndexOf("&expires"));
                AccessToken = strResponse.Replace("access_token=", "");
                streamIn.Close();
            }

            Facebook.FacebookAPI api = new Facebook.FacebookAPI(AccessToken);
            string requestEmail = "/me";
            JSONObject fbemail = api.Get(requestEmail);
            try
            {
                ViewBag.Email = fbemail.Dictionary["email"].String;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //errorLog.setError(ex, "LoginController.SaveFacebookData");
            }

            string Accounts = "/me/accounts";
            JSONObject pageData = api.Get(Accounts);
            var data = pageData.Dictionary["data"];
            List<JSONObject> pageList = data.Array.ToList<JSONObject>();
            ViewBag.pageList = pageList;
            foreach (var page in pageList)
            {

                try
                {
                   var id = page.Dictionary["id"].String;
                    string request = id;
                    JSONObject fbobject = api.Get(request);
                    try
                    {
                        ViewBag.BusinessName = fbobject.Dictionary["name"].String;
                        ViewBag.Address = fbobject.Dictionary["location"].ToDisplayableString();
                        ViewBag.PhoneNumber = fbobject.Dictionary["phone"].String;


                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        //errorLog.setError(ex, "LoginController.SaveFacebookData");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //errorLog.setError(ex, "LoginController.SaveFacebookData");
                }
            }
```

Comment: where do you guys keep copying your code from? status_update and offline_access are deprecated for years already.

Comment: archive.org... @luschn

Comment: @luschn - Facebook Developers Toolkit

Comment: that one? > https://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/ - it´s from 2010, you know.

Comment: @luschn- The thing is its working fine for my Facebook account where as if I try it on a different account it does not show the pages the account has even though they are present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I have Finally managed to get the desired result using #Remodal.js

<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery.remodal.css")">
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Home/jquery.remodal.js")"></script>
<div class="remodal" id="page-selector-remodal" data-remodal-id="pageselector">
        <p>Please select a facebook page Share </p>
        <div id="page-name-container">
            <select id="page-name" class="form-control">
            </select>
        </div>
        <a class="remodal-confirm" id="facebookPageSelectSubmit" href="#">OK</a>
        <a class="remodal-cancel" id="remodal-cancel" href="#">CANCEL</a>
    </div>

    <div data-remodal-id="modal-status">
        <p id="modal-status-content">
            The Account you have selected does not have Email.
        </p>
        <br>
        <a class="remodal-confirm" href="#">OK</a>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript>
 (function (d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s);
            js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.init({
                appId: 'YOUR APP ID',
                cookie: true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                // the session
                xfbml: true,  // parse social plugins on this page
                version: 'v2.2' // use version 2.1
            });
        };

        var pageSelector = $('[data-remodal-id=pageselector]').remodal();
        var modalstatus = $('[data-remodal-id=modal-status]').remodal();

        function statusChangeCallback(response) {

            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                // Logged into your app and Facebook.
                //testAPI();
            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
                $("#modal-status-content").empty().html(response.status);
                modalstatus.open();
            }

            else {
                $("#modal-status-content").empty().html(response.status);
                modalstatus.open();
                // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
                // they are logged into this app or not.
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
                    'into Facebook.';
            }
        }


        function FacebookHandler() {
            FB.login(function (result) {
                if (result != null && result.authResponse != null && result.authResponse != undefined) {
                    facebookPageData = result;
                    FB.api('/me/accounts', function (accountsResult) {
                        if (accountsResult != null && accountsResult.data.length != 0) {
                            //open the remodal here
                            pageSelector.open();
                            facebookAccountsData = accountsResult;
                            var data = accountsResult['data'];
                            if (data != null) {
                                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                    $("#page-name").append('<option value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].name + '</option>');
                                }
                            }
                            unblockUI('body');
                            $("#flip-container, #feature-container, #branding-container, #intro-arrow-container, #share-container, #copyright-text-container").hide();
                            $("body").css("padding-right", "0");
                        }
                        else {
                            $("#modal-status-content").empty().html("The Account you have selected does not have any facebook page,<br />Post to Wall.");
                            modalstatus.open();
                            pageSelector.open();
                            unblockUI('body');
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    $("#modal-status-content").empty().html("Unable to retrieve your details from facebook, try again after sometime.");
                    modalstatus.open();
                    unblockUI('body');
                }
            }, { scope: 'manage_pages, publish_stream' });
        }

        $("#facebookPageSelectSubmit").on("click", function () {
            var facebookpageId = $("#page-name option:selected").val();
            if (facebookpageId != null) {
                FB.api('/' + facebookpageId, function (identity) {

                    if (identity != null) {
                        FB.api('/' + facebookpageId, { fields: 'access_token' }, function (resp) {
                            if (resp.access_token != null) {
                                //Get the "resp"(Data) here
                        }
                        else {

                        }

                    });
                }

                else {

                }
            });
        }
        else {

        }
    });
</script>

//Finally call the "FacebookHandler()" function on click


</body>
```